# Keep applied filters on browser back and forward Angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, single-page-application

I have product listing page, where I do have all data to show user, if user is applying filters, I am filtering list on client side itself using Angular 2,

Now if user move forward to project details page and click browser back button, all applied filters vanished as it should be, But I need to implement so that on back button all applied filters should persist.

Solutions I am thinking: -

**Approach** : Whenever User apply filter we add that in URL and redirect.

**Problem** :  On every URL redirect API's will be called.

Is there a better way I can approach this problem ?

Comment: the question seems resolved but in any case this should help ; https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the filter criteria being visible in the URL (and to be bookmarkable) use router parameters and redirect to the URL containing the updated parameters. If you use `routerCanReuse() { return true; }, then the component is not even reloaded but just`routerOnReuse()` is called where you can acquire the updated parameters.

If you don't want the filter criteria to appear in the URL, use a shared service to store the parameters, then navigating doesn't destroy the parameter values. Ensure that the provider for the service is provide high enough (`AppComponent` for example) for it to not get destroyed when a component gets destroyed by routing away.

Comment: Can you please give example how can I use routerCanReuse and routerOnReuse in component

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/CanReuse-interface.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/OnReuse-interface.html. Seems it is not yet available in the new RC.1 router but will probably be provided with the next update.

Answer (score 2):

Storing things in the URL as arguments is a good approach, since you don't depend on hidden state (global application variables) to build your view.

However I'd not intercept the routing component, but rather use Angular's support for structured URLs and filter the data in the onInit method or whenever it is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the added condition that, I had to redirect the user back to listing page with the filters applied when he used the save functionality. 
The approach I used was to combing both a service and having filters in the URL parameters.

The reason to use both is,
You could enter the product detail page in 3 ways:

1. From Product Listing.
2. Directly from URL.
3. From some other, where you might have given the link.

And so you cannot just use `this._location.back();` as you might not want to redirect to the last page in all cases.
So my approach was to store the last URL in a service, and in the detail component check if there is any stored URL.

An important thing here is to check and pop the stored URL on the `ngOnInit()` as the user might not always click on save.

Attaching the code to the service, it's fairly basic.

```
@Injectable()
export class ReturnHistoryService {

   private _returnURL: string;

   saveReturnURL(returnURL: string) {
     this._returnURL = returnURL;
   }

   popReturnURL() {
       let returnURL = this._returnURL;
       this._returnURL = null;
       return returnURL;
   }
```

`

Make sure the provider is not per component.